# NodeJS Get every item in JSON without knowing the names

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

Essentially I get a JSON called allVariants after a GET request that looks like this:

```
{
    "194389689304": "140",
    "194389689311": "140",
    "194389689328": "140"
}
```

All I'm trying to do is get node to output this JSON as an array without the 140s however the 194389689304 parts change after every get request so they are not known prior.

Wanted Output: 194389689304,194389689311,194389689328

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Object.keys**:

```
a = {
    "194389689304": "140",
    "194389689311": "140",
    "194389689328": "140"
}

Object.keys(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys(yourObj)` to get all the keys of your object.

Demo:

```js
let yourObj = {
    "194389689304": "140",
    "194389689311": "140",
    "194389689328": "140"
};

console.log(Object.keys(yourObj));
```